Azure WebApp Blazor with IdentityServer4 Couldn't find a valid certificate with subject 'CN=' on the 'CurrentUser\My'
I used self-signed certificate for my IS4. I followed the steps in here.
I tried using self-signed certificate and uploading the pfx file.
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=certName" -CertStoreLocation "cert:LocalMachine\My"
With the following in appsetings.json:
"IdentityServer": { "Key": { "Type": "Store", "StoreName": "My", "StoreLocation": "CurrentUser", "Name": "CN=certName" } }
As described in the doc, I attached the certificate to the web app by setting configuration WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES to the thumbprint from uploaded certificate. Setting it to * also didn't help. This is the same for certificates from Azure KeyVault.
But, from the logs it seems like the web app/IdentityServer couldn't get the certificate with the given subject.
System.InvalidOperationException: Couldn't find a valid certificate with subject 'CN=certName' on the 'CurrentUser\My'. The app couldn't start and throws 503.
I use Duende which is the latest version of IdentityServer. Did I miss something?

The problem is related to Linux VM used for the web app. The IdentityServer Key value I used is for Windows and that was not working in Linux.
I got the answer from here
I use this instead:
"Key": {
      "Type": "File",
      "FilePath": "/var/ssl/private/ThumbprintValueHERE.p12",
      "Password": ""
}

